# jQuery and non-unicode characters

Tags: jquery, character-encoding, non-unicode

I'm trying to use jQuery to get autocomplete from a database. It works fine with English values but I have some rows in Arabic and they are showing as (????).

I start all my pages with:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<Link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

My database is formatted in UTF8. I also include the connection to DB file which says :

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ($dberror1);
mysql_select_db("finishing", $conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')
```

Note: all my other items in Arabic work fine. It's just the jQuery autocomplete that I am having issues with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is solved , simply by including the connection to DB script in the search file , apparently when i was referring to an external file there was a conflict of variables.
The script that worked is exactly what i previously posted .. 
What amazed me though, is that i spent all day looking thru the internet and there aren't any clear answers to the non-unicode problem .. 
Therefore i advise (in my humble opinion to always include these 4 lines of script in all your files in you are working in a non unicode language ..thankyou for everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

Change the charset type in meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=charset=iso-8859-6">
```

`charset=iso-8859-6` is used to support the Arabic language in HTML page on browser.

**EDITED:**

Well This will be helpful to you sure.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-6">
// your code from where you are making the auto complete 
// either ajax request or any thing
</script>
```

Just add this charset in your script tag.

For more information [see link](http://joconner.com/2008/09/javascript-file-encoding/).

Comment: @HussamSibai try with `charset=windows-1256`. may be this will be helpful to you?

Comment: just to make sure i explained myself well ..the whole page shows fine , including the arabic charachters ..the only problem is with the field that shows jquery autocomplete results from the data base ..thank you

Comment: i been trying with it all afternoon but nothing  .. im starting to think this would have to do with changing the script within the .js file